# how to write an envoy filter to allow http version 1.0 into the kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, istio-gateway, istio-sidecar

curl response>> HTTP/1.1 426 Upgrade Required

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: http10-filter
spec:
  workloadSelector:
    labels:
      istio: ingress
  configPatches:
    - applyTo: NETWORK_FILTER
      match:
        context: GATEWAY
        listener:
          filterChain:
            filter:
              name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
      patch:
        operation: INSERT_BEFORE
        value:
          name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
          typed_config:
            "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.config.filter.network.http_connection_manager.v2.HttpConnectionManager
            stat_prefix: ingress_http
            http_filters:
              - name: envoy.filters.http.http_protocol_options
                typed_config:
                  "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.config.filter.http.http_protocol_options.v2.HttpProtocolOptions
                  enable_http1: true
                  allow_absolute_url: true
              - name: envoy.filters.http.router
```

Error from server: error when creating ".\http10-envoy-filter.yml": admission webhook "validation.istio.io" denied the request: configuration is invalid: Envoy filter: can't unmarshal Any nested proto type.googleapis.com/envoy.config.filter.network.http_connection_manager.v2.HttpConnectionManager: could not resolve Any message type: type.googleapis.com/envoy.config.filter.http.http_protocol_options.v2.HttpProtocolOptions

Comment: If you want to use EnvoyFilter you need to upgrade your Istio to the latest version. Other option is using the old docs and modify your filter to work with the old api: [Envoy Filter](https://istio.io/v1.2/docs/reference/config/networking/v1alpha3/envoy-filter/).

Comment: > istioctl version \n
client version: 1.11.6 \n
control plane version: 1.15.2 \n
data plane version: 1.15.2 (11 proxies) \n

is there any other way I can allow http1.0 traffic in?

Comment: Check you may need **Kind: IstioOperator**, you need HTTP 1.0 enabled on the ingress gateway and between sidecars. Refer to [Github issue #13085](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/13085) & [Configure envoy to accept HTTP version 1.0](https://discuss.istio.io/t/configure-envoy-to-accept-http-version-1-0/11544), which may help to resolve your issue.